# Batch multiple texts in single json

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to combine multiple texts from a pandas DataFrame into one JSON in order to batch them for HTTP requets and speed up the process of the requests.
Right now I loop over every single element and then create one request for each, so like this:

```
for i, row in tqdm(taskfiles.text.items()):
  response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers,json={"text": json.dumps(row)})
```

The desired form looks like this:

```
{ "input": [
    {
         "text": "this is a patient."
    },
    {
         "text": "this is another patient."
    }
   ]
}
```

I can't grasp how I effectively create a JSON file containing multiple items instead of one

This is what i tried:

```
container = []

for i, row in taskfiles.text.items():
    container.append({"text" + json.dumps(row)})

batch = {"input": json.dumps(container)}
```

It raises an error: "TypeError: Object of type 'set' is not JSON serializable"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always ALWAYS tell us which line raised the error! In this case, it's easy. You have a `+` where you should have a `:`.

```
    container.append({"text": json:dumps(row)})
```